# iOS - views positioning and sizing

Tags: ios, view, position, positioning

I would like to ask you what is the best way (in iOS) to position some views when you dont know what size they have to be to fit the content.

Heres example:
I want to make a page where there are multiple texts vertically sorted with some spaces between them and some of them can me multiline. You dont know the contents of those labels yet, you get them from JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about how to display a collection of unknown strings then the answer is probably to use a UITableView. [Here's](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/) a good tutorial.

But if you're asking a question regarding the positioning and sizing of a view in general, the question is way too general and can't really be answered properly.

Comment: No, I mean views in general. You want them to be just as big as they need to fit their content in and right below show another view again fitted to its content. I guess I am thinking of something like relative positioning and autosizing?

Comment: Again, this question is way too general and requires exploration of iOS's many views and controls. Once you've experimented a bit with these views, including their frame.origin and frame.size properties, you'll have a better understanding and will be able to focus your question.

Comment: i understand it well. What I am looking for some solution or way for adding views that will position themself automaticaly one after another. I guess you can call it relative positioning. Because right now I have to be counting  pixels to make sure no views are not overlapping.

Comment: And why is UITableViewController not an adequate solution for this?

Comment: Well. you are probably right, it seems like a good solution, but compared to other solutions provided in other languages it seems a little .... eehmm ... off, not right. I dont know.

Comment: There may be a lot of alternatives but they really do depend on what you're trying to do. I would recommend browsing through cocoacontrols.com - they have loads of good solutions for resizeable views based on various collections.